# Example of prompting for admin access in Windows CMD file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, uac

I'm writing a command file (.cmd) to add a user to a local group. I would like to have the CMD file prompt for admin access if the call fails.

I imagine it would ne something like this:

```
@echo off
net localgroup administrators domain\user /add

rem The Net command doesn't prompt for privilege escalation, it just fails.
if "%errorlevel%" neq "0" RequireAdministrator "cmd.exe /c net localgroup administrators domain\user /add"

if "%errorlevel%" neq "0" echo Could not add user to administrators group
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: Why not just run the command "net localgroup..." directly, see if it succeeds and prompt if it doesn't?

Comment: The issue is that net.exe doesn't prompt you if you don't have access. Specifically, I need a means to elevate the priviledge. I'll edit for clarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a well known script published by Microsoft known as `elevate`. It comes in the form of the Elevation PowerToys. You can down load it from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.06.elevation.aspx?pr=blog).

The two files you need are `elevate.vbs` and `elevate.cmd`. Put those in the same directory as your .cmd file, or perhaps somewhere on your system path. Then your .cmd file should just read:

```
elevate cmd.exe /c net localgroup administrators domain\user /add
```